# Rounded corners in TikZ trees

Tags: tree, tikz

When I use TikZ tree with nodes with rounded corners, the connecting lines do not touch the nodes (near corners) but end where would rectangle end. Is there an easy way around it?

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty tree structure, and then place the nodes on top of the tree structure.

See *Naming Child Nodes* [in the pgfmanual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) for an example.